# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: in my array

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I have an array that runs on recursion it finds the minimum number on the array. I run the program and I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error on (Assignment9.java:36) 
 if (previousMin > numbers[endIndex]) and  (Assignment9.java:20)
double min =  findMin(numbers, 0, numbers.length); I know why this problem usually occurs but I cant find the fix for my code. I dont know if my actual code works since I cant run the program. Any suggestions..

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.text.*;


  public class Assignment9

  {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{


    int [] numbers = new int[100];


    InputStreamReader streamR = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader inFile = new BufferedReader(streamR);
    String reader = inFile.readLine();

    double min =  findMin(numbers, 0, numbers.length);
    System.out.print ("The minimum number is " + min + ('\n'));

}


public static int findMin (int [] numbers, int startIndex, int endIndex)

     {
         if (startIndex == endIndex)
         {
             return numbers[startIndex];
         }
         else 
         { 

               double previousMin = findMin (numbers, startIndex, endIndex - 1);
               if (previousMin > numbers[endIndex])


             return numbers[endIndex];

         else

         return numbers[endIndex];
         }


}
```

Comment: array[array.length], by definition, for any array ever, always throws an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 4):

You are accessing `numbers[endIndex]` where `endIndex = numbers.length`. This is not possible in java since array indexing starts at 0, the last element is at index `length-1`, hence the exception.

Answer (score 3):

numbers.length will return the length of your array, starting from 1.  You want to use numbers.length - 1 in your method call

Answer (score 0):

An array of 100 elements has them numbered from 0 to 99.  But you are using 100 as `endIndex` in your initial call to `findMin`.  So when you reference `numbers[endIndex]`, you've gone past the end of the array - `numbers[100]` does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You should use numbers.length-1 for your end index because java is zero-indexed, and numbers.length will be outside the bounds of the array. Returning the value numbers[startIndex] will be out of bounds when startIndex==endIndex.